# Associated Data Not Returned From Apollo to Client?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Here's relevant Apollo code. (Many database fields have been omitted to make it faster/easier to read this post.)

**CONNECTORS**

```
const userAccountsDataModel = db.define('userAccountsData', {
    id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
    picture_medium: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});


const associatesDataModel =  db.define('associatesData', {
    _id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
    first_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    last_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    userID: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
});

associatesDataModel.belongsTo(userAccountsDataModel, {foreignKey: 'userID'});
```

**SCHEMA**

```
type userAccountsData {
    id: String
    picture_medium: String
}

type associatesData {
    _id: String
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    userID: String
    userAccountsData: [userAccountsData]
}
```

**QUERY**

```
const GETONEASSOCIATE_QUERY = gql`
query getOneAssociate($_id: String!) {
  getOneAssociate(_id: $_id) {
    _id
    first_name
    last_name
    userID 
    accountsData{
        id
        picture_medium
      }
  }
} `;
```

**RESOLVER**

```
getOneAssociate(_, args)  {
    console.log('in getOneAssociate');
    var ret = connectors.associatesData.findAll({
        where: args,
        include: [connectors.userAccountsData],
        logging: console.log
    }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));

    return ret;
},
```

Via Sequelize, the resolver generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "associatesData"."_id", 
       "associatesData"."first_name", 
       "associatesData"."last_name", 
       "associatesData"."userID", 
       "userAccountsDatum"."id" AS "userAccountsDatum.id", 
       "userAccountsDatum"."picture_medium" AS "userAccountsDatum.picture_medium" 
FROM "associatesDatas" AS "associatesData" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "userAccountsData" AS "userAccountsDatum" 
                ON "associatesData"."userID" = "userAccountsDatum"."id" 
WHERE "associatesData"."_id" = '35';
```

When I run the above SQL in my SQL client, I can see that all the data sought is being returned, including the data from the related "userAccountsData" table.

However, when the data gets to my client code running in javascript the browser, the data from the related table is missing-- the object that should contain it is null.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance to all for any info!

Comment: There's no need to do `res.map((item) => item.dataValues)`. Try to return whole `res`

Comment: While there is no need for `res.map`, returning the whole `res` did not resolve the anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an anomaly with Sequelize's automatic pluralizing of table names.

By default, Sequelize automatically pluralizes table names. It is supposed to be possible to turn this behavior off by using Sequelize's `freezeTableName` property. However, per [this Sequelize issue post](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1808), there are cases in which Sequelize ignores the `freezeTableName` property and pluralizes (and sometimes singularizes) the table names anyway.

After discovering this I was able to resolve the anomaly by pluralizing the relevant table name and going through all my Apollo code to update the references to this table so that they would be pluralized as well.